# Python: define a log likelihood function

Tags: function, python-2.7

Let's say I have some data `z=[1,2,3,4]`

I am trying to fit this data to a model which is known, so the exercise is simply to find the value of an unknown parameter D 
My log likelihood function looks like this

```
l(D|z)= \sum(\sqrt(z^2 + D^2))
```

I am trying to define this log likelihood function, z is the data which is a list and theta is the parameter vector which in this case is 1 dimensional

```
import scipy.optimize as op
import numpy as np

D_true = some given value 
def f(z,theta):
     D=theta
     z2=[x**2 for x in z]
     return np.sqrt(np.sum(z2 + D**2))

result = op.minimize(f, D_true,args=(z))
print result.x
```

But I am getting the error message `unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'`
 and pointing towards `return np.sqrt(np.sum(z2 + D**2))`

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: The exception pretty clearly suggests that `D` (and thus the `theta` argument to the function) is a list rather than a scalar. Lists don't have (most) mathematical operators defined, so you're getting an error. I don't know enough about scipy to tell what you're doing wrong, but I'd guess you're passing the wrong args somewhere. I'd also suggest using numpy arrays, rather than lists if you need to do mathematical operations. `z2 + D**2` is probably going to fail even for a scalar `D` since `z2` is a list.

Comment: Exactly! I understand that D is being considered as a list, how do I define a function in which I can specify that D is a parameter and not a list?

Answer (score 0):

as they say, "we have eyes, if we only but see." What I mean is, it's telling you where to look

"But I am getting the error message unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
and pointing towards return np.sqrt(np.sum(z2 + D**2))"

and it's even telling you the problem: you cannot add a list object to an int object. By the way you wrote it, I think you are assuming Python will broadcast, but it will not do that unless at least one of the objects is a numpy (`ndarray`) object.

You probably wanted the value `D ** 2`  to be added to each entry of z2. One option is to write

```
return np.sqrt(np.sum(z2 + D **2 * np.ones_like(z2)))
```

another option is

```
return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.array(z2) + D ** 2))
```

It's awkward to me to see lists being used with numpy functions, you may consider working exclusively with numpy arrays. For example, you wouldn't have run into this problem if you opted to do that from the start.

If you had a numpy array, you can use ufuncs instead of list comprehensions.

```
z = np.arange(1,5)
z2 = z ** 2
```

is the same as

```
z2 = [x ** 2 for x in z]
```

but returns a numpy array instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `D = theta` by `D, = theta` since theta is a list. This way we unpack it on the fly.